Hanoi graph in Mathematica
Is hanoi graph available in Mathematica program?
if so, can you show me the code while if not, can we input or build the hanoi graph?

See this notebook at the MathWorld page.

Row[GraphData[{"Hanoi", #}] & /@ Range[5]]

You could define the function like:
HanoiGraph[n_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Block[{coords, edges},
        coords = Fold[Flatten[Through[{TranslationTransform[{0,0}],TranslationTransform[ 2^(#2-1){-1,-Sqrt[3]}],TranslationTransform[ 2^(#2-1){1,-Sqrt[3]}]}[#]],1]&,
            {{0,0},{-(1/2),-(Sqrt[3]/2)},{1/2,-(Sqrt[3]/2)}}, Range[n - 1]];
        edges = Fold[Flatten[{#,#+Max[#] ,#+Max[#] 2,{{1/2 (1+3^#2),1+3^#2},{2 3^#2,1/2 (1+5 3^#2)},{3^#2,1+2 3^#2}} },1]&, {{1,2},{2,3},{3,1}},Range[n - 1]];
        Graph[Range[Max[edges]], UndirectedEdge@@@edges, VertexCoordinates -> coords, opts]
    
    ]

Multicolumn[Table[HanoiGraph[n], {n, 8}]]


